# Attach event listener to dom fragment

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to attach `"onchange"` event listener to a dom fragment but it's not working properly.

For example I have the following code:

```
$(function(){
  var elements = [
    '<input type="checkbox" name="one" value="kung" />',
    '<input type="checkbox" name="one" value="fu" />'
  ];

  var fragment = $(document.createDocumentFragment());

  fragment.on('change', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function(){
    alert('my kung fu is strong');
  });

  $.each(elements, function(index, element){
    fragment.append(element);
    fragment.find('input:last-child').trigger('change');
  });
});
```

However the attach event listener is not working. But if I attach the event handler in the loop like this it will work:

```
fragment.find('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function(){
  alert('this works, but it is not ok');
});
```

I do not want to set the event listener in the loop as I feel it will slow down the script and it's an overkill.

Also I need to mention that my array of of elements is quite big.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Document fragments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment) don't have `addEventListener` or similar. They're a subinterface of [`Node`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node) that also implement [`ParentNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode), but not [`EventTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget).

Your options are:

1. Attach the handlers directly to the `input`s (which you've said you don't want to do), or
2. Add a top-level container element to the fragment that contains the `input`s, and put the event handler on that instead.
3. Attach the handler to the document you add the document fragment to (if your code is involved in that)

Comment: You are a genius, your #2 option works like a charm, thank you. As for #3 I know that also works, but I can not append the fragment until all elements are appended, due to reflow which slows down the script, and I need the onchange event triggered right after each element is appended.